# Получить значение функции

Tags: javascript, функции

Можно ли получить значение функции first из функции calc? Я знаю как идет вызов функций, но без понятия как получить значение ещё не выполненной функции

```
    function first() {
        //console.log(first.arguments);
        return 10
    }

    function second() {
        return 20
    }

    function calc(param) {
        return param + calc.caller;
    }

    first(calc(second()));
```

Comment: Почитайте про *области видимости.*

Comment: Как вообще можно думать, что не выполненный код, можно контролировать? Как можно купив хлеба, не заплатив не рубля?

Comment: ну тогда как изменить последовательность выполнения функций?

Comment: caller возвращает null, так как calc вызывается из главной функции, а не внутри кода функции first(). В данном случае calc() никак не может узнать что ее значение будет использовано для first().

Comment: Ну есть же какой нибудь способ это решить?

Comment: афффтар.... жжет.... Ника кнельзя узнать, еще 300 раз повторить, нельзя, нельзя, нельзя, нельзя, нельзя, нельзя. нельзя. мЫнус АдыН1!!!

Comment: Нашел решение  .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    function first(operator) {
        return operator ? operator(10) : 10
    }

    function second(operator) {
        return operator ? operator(20) : 20
    }

    function calc(rightVal) {
        return  function(leftVal){
            return leftVal + rightVal
        }
    }

    console.log(first(calc(second())));
```